# why Nginx container cannot resolve redis container by name?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, lua

I have a docker-compose that run two containers, one an Nginx with Lua-module and another is a simple
Redis, here is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: local_nginx
    image: danday74/nginx-lua
    ports: 
      - 8089:80
      - 8053:8053
    volumes: 
      - /home/navid/lua_project/nginx/nginx.conf:/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
      - /home/navid/lua_project/nginx/www:/nginx/html
      - /home/navid/lua_project/lib/resty/redis.lua:/usr/local/share/luajit-2.0.4/resty/redis.lua
  redis: 
    container_name: local_redis
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
```

In my nginx.conf I define one route to execute an Lua script file. this is the conf file:

```
events {}
http {
    server {
        server_name lua;
        listen 8053;
        location /redis-request {  
            content_by_lua_file /nginx/html/my_redis.lua;
        }
    }   
}
```

and in my_redis file I am trying to connect to Redis container with [this](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-redis#connect) library,
I paste my code below:

```
local redis = require "resty.redis"
    local red = redis:new()

    -- 1 sec
    red:set_timeout(1000) 

    -- or connect to a unix domain socket file listened
    -- by a redis server:
    -- local ok, err = red:connect("unix:/path/to/redis.sock")
    local ok, err = red:connect("local_redis.lua_project_default", 6379)
    if not ok then
        ngx.say("failed to connect: ", err)
        return
    end
```

but when I am trying to send my request to Nginx by my browser I am getting such error:

> failed to connect: no resolver defined to resolve "local_redis.lua_project_default"

how can I prevent the Nginx to try local service names?

**Update**
when id add *resolve 127.0.0.11;* tag to my Nginx config file the error changed to:

> failed to connect: connection refused

but I can make a telnet connection to my Redis container from Nginx.

Comment: I think it should work if you drop the domain name (e.g., just use `local_redis` rather than `local_redis.lua_project_default`). Note that you can use either the service name (`redis` or `nginx`) or the container name (`local_redis`, `local_nginx`).

Comment: I checked both of local_redis and local_redis and Lua_project_default but didnot change any things. But service name is an option to try.

Comment: This all just worked when I tried it (docker version 20.10.4 on Linux).

Comment: With my orginal config or with service name?

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment, either the service or the container name worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution but I did not the root cause of problem:

I changed my Nginx-Lua image from *danday74/nginx-lua* to **fabiocicerchia/nginx-lua**, and It worked like a charm. the first one was created on Nginx version 1.16 and the last one was created by Nginx 1.19.

Comment: So I'm actually using fabiocicerchia/nginx-lua and just hit this issue. Did you ever work out the root cause?

Comment: no, there was no more time to spent on this issue